# How can I modify SweetAlert2's Toast animation settings?

Tags: css, sweetalert2

I have implemented [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io)'s toast notifications into my web application and overridden the animation with the `customClass` parameter to allow my toast notification to slide in from the right hand side.  However, I cannot seem to work out two other details:

1. How can I speed up the notification animation?  It takes about 2 seconds for the notification to begin sliding in from the right.  I want to make this instant. The only value I'm aware of is `timer` which controls how long the notification is visible for.
2. How can I make my toast notification slide in 'under' my top navigation bar?  Is there a way I can adjust the top offset (or top margin) on where the notification starts from?  So for example, can I set the top of the toast notification to a specific value (say `100px` from the top of screen)?

My current code snippet looks like this:

```
const toast = swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    position: 'top-end',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 10000,
    animation: false,
    customClass: 'animated slideInRight'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By specifying the `css`, you might need to tweak a bit depending on your project.

For your first question to speed up animation you can add on your animation:

```
.swal2-show {
  animation: swal2-show .5s !important; 
}
```

To modify your modal you can modify:

```
.swal2-modal {
  background-color: rgba(63,255,106,0.69) !important;
  border: 3px solid white;
  position: relative !important;
  top: 100px !important;
}
```

Example:

```js
swal('Custom animation speed')
```

```css
.swal2-show {
  animation: swal2-show .5s !important; 
}
.swal2-modal {
  background-color: rgba(63,255,106,0.69) !important;
  border: 3px solid white;
  position: relative !important;
  top: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7"></script>
```

Note that `!important` shouldn't be carelessly used, if you know the direct selector it always better to specify rather than using `!important`

Update for `Toast`: You need to change `.swal2-popup.swal2-toast.swal2-show`

```
.swal2-popup.swal2-toast.swal2-show {
  background-color: rgba(63,255,106,0.69) !important;
  border: 3px solid white;
  position: relative !important;
  top: 20px !important;
  -webkit-animation: swal2-show .5s !important;
  animation: swal2-show .5s !important;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZwpYrg)

Comment: This doesn't seem to modify the `toast` characteristics at all.  I ended up having to use `body.swal2-toast-shown .swal2-container.swal2-top-right{}` to modify the behaviour of the top offset, however, I can't seem to tap into the animation speed.

Comment: @Riples Can you add a working `toast` example which you mean? So far I only found sweetalert2 modal and jquery toast not sweetalert2 toast.

Comment: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#configuration  - at the bottom of the configuration options is a mixin example that demonstrates a toast notification for SweetAlert2

Comment: I created a new custom CSS class and added the animation and speed in there and it seems to have fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying the properties of the pop-up by using this code:

```js
Swal.fire({
      icon: "success",
      title: "Success title!",
      text: "Success Body",
      toast: true,
      position: "top-right",
      showClass: {
        popup: "animate__animated animate__bounceInRight",
      },
      hideClass: {
        popup: "animate__animated animate__bounceOutRight",
      },
    });
```

In showClass and hideClass, you can give the popup property a custom CSS to control the animation of the toast.

This has worked for me.